# Setting individual facet axes with facet_grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a faceted plot where each individual facet has different scales for both the x and y axes, and I would like to fit each facet axis to that scale. However, the `scales='free'` option only sets the scale separately for each axis independently, not for each facet. For instance, in the following minimal example:

```
library(ggplot2)
sample_dat = data.frame(X=rep(c('A','A','B','B'), each=10), 
  Y = rep(c('A','B','A','B'), each=10), 
  DX = c(rnorm(10,0,5), rnorm(10,5,5), rnorm(10,-5,5), rnorm(10,20,5)),
  DY = c(rnorm(10,0,5), rnorm(10,-15,5), rnorm(10,25,5), rnorm(10,5,5)))
ggplot(sample_dat, aes(x=DX, y=DY)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(X~Y, scales='free')
```

The graph below results where the x-axis varies between the A and B columns, but is fixed across both of the rows, and vice versa for the x-axis.

[image: Plot from minimal example]

Is there any way to plot with individual x and y axes for each of the four facets so that there are not large spaces with no data?

Comment: `facet_wrap` instead of `facet_grid` should work for you. Something like `ggplot(sample_dat, aes(x = DX, y = DY)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~X*Y, scales = "free")`?

Comment: Thanks! This does fix the issue with the scales, but is there any way to get the facet labels to work like they did with `facet_grid`? With this code each facet is labeled with both categories on top rather than labeling them on both the top and sides to fill the grid.